# How could I works with Gson when JSON returns Null?

Tags: json, gson

I have a JSON that returns some objects with value "null". I'm trying this values and add in my Object Class using Gson. The problem is when this value equals null I can't do it works because throws an exception "NullPointerException". If JSON object no has null value I can works but if has null value I can't

How could I do this works with null value ?

**JSON**

```
"Cotacao": {
   "endereco": null,
   "bairro": null,
   "cidade": null      
}
```

**Class Object**

```
public class Cotacao implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String endereco;
    private String bairro;
    private String cidade;
    //gets sets
```

**Get Values GSON**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JSONObject jsoCotacao = jsoObj.getJSONObject("Cotacao");
Cotacao cotacao = gson.fromJson(jsoCotacao.toString(), Cotacao.class);
```

Comment: What's `jsoObj` and what does `getJSONObject` do? Can you post the relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I did

```
public class GsonNullObject<T> implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {

        Class<T> rawType = (Class<T>) type.getRawType();
        if (rawType != String.class) {
            return null;
        }
        return (TypeAdapter<T>) new StringAdapter();
    }
}


public class StringAdapter extends TypeAdapter<String> {
    public String read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            reader.nextNull();
            return "";
        }
        return reader.nextString();
    }
    public void write(JsonWriter writer, String value) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
            writer.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        writer.value(value);
    }
}
```

**To use**

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(new GsonNullObject<Cotacao>()).create();
```